# Listening for messages in Discord.py while retaining commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

What I'm aiming to do is have my bot always listen for specific messages in discord.py. In the example, the message it should be listening for is $greet which it should respond to with "Say hello" read aloud in Text To Speech.

This works fine, however it disables regular commands I have setup like !play and !help. Is there anyway to get around this limitation?

Example code:

```
@my_bot.event
async def on_message(message, timeout=10,):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        await my_bot.send_message(message.channel, 'Say hello', tts=True)
        msg = await my_bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='hello')
        await my_bot.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello.')
```

Expected output:

```
User: !play
Bot: Now playing...
User: $greet
Bot: Say hello
```

Actual output:

```
User: !play
User: $greet
Bot: Say hello
```

Comment: What you're​ doing is overriding the default on_message event in the bot which was handling the command running. Since you do want special behaviour in this event this is correct but you need to call the method which handles command running afterwards. You might be able to find this in the module source (have a search for on_message) and I'll post an answer with it when I get home

Comment: Appreciate this greatly Blimmo, would upvote as this does seem to be the issue but I don't often use Stack Overflow so I can't figure out how. I'll have a search myself and look forward to hearing back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using the commands part of the discord.py module you rely on the instance of `Bot` calling your commands for any of them to happen. This is done by the bot's coroutine method `process_commands` in a complicated way which I'm not going to interpret.

From [the source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/bot.py):

```
# command processing

@asyncio.coroutine
def process_commands(self, message):
    ...
```

This is turn is called by the `on_message` event.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_message(self, message):
    yield from self.process_commands(message)
```

When you override the `on_message` event to implement your custom behaviour, you are replacing this default behaviour, so you'll need to call `process_commands` yourself after your special processing.

From [the docstring](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/bot.py) for the `process_commands` coroutine:

> By default, this coroutine is called inside the :func:`on_message`
>   event. If you choose to override the :func:`on_message` event, then
>   you should invoke this coroutine as well.

You can do this using putting this:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

at the end of your `on_message` event

I did something like this:

```
if message.channel.is_private:
    # Handle commands
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    await bot.delete_message(message)
```

to only allow commands in private messages and delete the command message after.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in separate files. Or you can just have them use the same prefix '!'

Comment: The prefix in the sample code is being used as a placeholder. In practice it should respond to specific phrases beginning with specific wording. For instance, if a user were to specifically start a phrase with the wording "Hello bot" it would reply. Converting the prefix doesn't assist in this as it still has to look for the prefix. From my understanding of the API my code should work, although obviously I've made a mistake. Can you give me an example of what you mean by "put them in separate files"?